# Javascript property: Built out of strings

Tags: javascript, string, javascript-objects

I need to built a object property out of strings
but how could I use the value of this string as property name?

```
var x = 'a';
var y = 'b';
var xy = x + y;

var z = {
    xy: 'some text'
};
```

Now I could access it via `z['xy']` but not via `z['ab']`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to write

```
var z = {};
z[xy] = 'some text';
```

You cannot do this using an object literal.

Comment: Okay and how could I do this (without object literal)?

Answer (score 0):

As [@SLaks has said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108675/572939) - its not possible with object literals ... you could use an array though :

```
var x = 'a';
var y = 'b';
var xy = x + y;

var z = [];  // define array
z[xy]='some text';​​​
alert(z['ab']); // outputs 'some text'
​
```